# How to integrate Map Reduce programs with Web Application

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, spark-java

I am currently working on a web application. The requirement is something like the User will upload excel or Csv files, containing large Datasets from a front end framework.

Once uploaded the data will be processed based on many parameters like duplication check, individual field validations etc. 
The user should be able to download the results based on the filters instantly in the form of newly generated csv files.

The technologies I am using is Hbase for storing the User information like name, email & so. Once the data is uploaded by the User it will be stored and processed in HDFS. The backend I have written in sparkjava web framework. Now the data processing engine I have used is MapReduce.

For MapReduce, I have written multiple Mappers, Reducers, Driver classes in Java which are present inside the same project Directory, but the issue is I am not able to integrate MapReduce with my backend. Once the data is uploaded, the Mapreduce programs should run. I am not able to do that.

Can anyone please suggest me any ideas regarding this. I am new to Hadoop, so please do tell me if I am doing anything wrong & suggest a better alternative for this. Any help will be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: How large datasets do you want to process? Hadoop Mapreduce can be beneficial for datasets like >1TB (or at least for datasets, that not fit into RAM of a single server).

Comment: Records will vary from 1 million to 10 million at a time. Here MapReduce is used to fast process those csv or excel files. Is the same possible any other way?

Comment: Hadoop is more for scalable processing and speed is not the priority of this engine. Did you consider single-server solutions for processing? Frameworks depend on the language you want to use. E.g. data.table is efficient for single-server processing. Here is a benchmark of several tools: https://github.com/szilard/benchm-databases

Comment: No I haven't considered Single Server Solutions as this project was already running when I joined in. Is it possible to integrate single server solutions with Web-app??

Comment: Yes, it is. For Hadoop it will be just scheduling a job on the backend side. The job can take a long time, so you shouldn't wait (in a blocking way) for results. Monitoring if results are available will be better than waiting.

Comment: Alright, 1 more thing, which one will be best option in your opinion...?

Comment: I will study that and try to implement it.. Thanks mate.. :)